# Como abrir varias veces una vista en vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Tengo una app donde envio un formato pdf que genero desde una vista, esta desarrollada en vuejs, no tengo problemas al generar una, pero me han pedido que sea con una seleccion multiple..

lo que hacia era mandar por medio de vuex el id del documento que iba a traer la informacion y en el create de la vista mandaba llamar la data y en el beforeDestroy mandaba el codigo html ya con la data y en el back generaba el id y lo enviaba al correo, pero ahora al querer meterlo en un ciclo for

```
for (let oc of this.fOrdenes) {
  this.$store.commit("setOc", { numoc: oc.OC_id });
  this.$router.push({ name: "templateoc" }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
}
```

solo manda un solo formato, y me da el error

> Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location:
> "/templateoc"

investigando solo me dan la recomendacion para evitar que salga el error.

si tendran alguna idea, vista o documentacion se los agradeceria

Comment: no entiendo cual seria el problema... o cual es el problema que tenes...

Comment: perdona, listo ya he modificado la pregunta